# Using docker container in vscode but no image(png/jpg) shows

Tags: docker, image, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I am using the docker container in vscode studio but I am not able to open images(png/jpg/any other image format) in vscode studio. Is there any extension I am missing container?
How can I view images?

This is the error I got always

```
cannot open
docker://ab3e3b80169f48c1207ff7834e6ece2de654f32980944eeb0c211f3f70978f5f/home/farah/heart_ct/knight/data/knu/mml/cross_validation_code/CAC_colored_CT_image/18/CNN2/001.jpg?fileType%3Dfile%26containerOS%3Dlinux%26path%3D%252Fhome%252Ffarah%252Fheart_ct%252Fknight%252Fdata%252Fknu%252Fmml%252Fcross_validation_code%252FCAC_colored_CT_image%252F18%252FCNN2%252F001.jpg. Detail: File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text
```

I had created my docker image using the following statements

```
FROM mirasysindia/pytorch1.7-cuda11.0-py3.8-opencv4.2:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim && apt-get install -y screen && apt-get install -y ssh  
RUN apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y build-essential 
RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx && apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev
RUN apt-get install htop 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git
WORKDIR /home/farah/
```

I mostly used vim to write my code

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the docker extension could not open the file,
and I tried other extensions too.
So you can just download by right clicking on the image.